# Do we need community promotion ads?

Tags: discussion, support, community-moderation

Other meta sites have this feature and it seems quite popular.

Some example: [physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015), [math](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015), [unix](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3311/community-promotion-ads-2015), [security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/community-promotion-ads-2015).

I think, it would be a wonderful way to promote other german SE sites, for example...

[image: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54232/stack-overflow-in-german?referrer=_ku8R6AQtKde3a1DrmcTkQ2]

Comment: Just create a meta question that asks people to create site ads, like we did [over at Language Learning Stack Exchange](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/231/create-an-ad-for-this-site). Ads that get more than x votes (5 was the number on LLSE) are selected for use on other SE sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Community Promotion Ads](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) were introduced to give any public SE community a tool to promote things:

> The goal is to help visitors find out about the cool stuff your community is doing and help promote activities they find important.

This feature is not available for sites in public beta but is very welcome on all graduate sites.

It is a very good means to promote **us** on **other** sites of the network where we are a member but we can not yet publish any such ad on our site.

Also see:

- [Community ads FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237281/community-ads-faq)

Comment: There’s [no strict or technical reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248214/how-do-we-get-community-promotion-ads-on-beta-sites) against having them, though. If we as a community of an [established beta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) *absolutely* wanted them, we might possibly get them. The votes on this question, however, don’t make me very optimistic.