# Do we want to promote German Language at other SE sites?

Tags: discussion

Graduated sites have (or can get) [community-ads](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads). It’s a way to promote related [SE sites](http://stackexchange.com), [Area51 proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com) or really anything of interest to the local community (e.g. events, software, websites). They’re proposed on `meta` and usually need 6 up votes to become live in the sidebar.

It has already been asked [whether we wanted the feature](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/834/do-we-need-community-promotion-ads). I’m asking whether and how we want to promote German Language SE on other sites using community promotion ads, e.g. on

- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) (for Yiddish)
- [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)
- [Japanese Language](http://japanese.stackexchange.com)
- [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)

or, still in public beta without community promos:

- [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)
- [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)
- [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) and [… of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)
- [Genealogy & Family History](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/)
- [Beer](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/)
- every other … Language site, incl. one proposed or in private beta.

I expect `No` answers to explain their reasoning, but `Yes` answers to propose an actual poster or at least provide some ideas for one.

Comment: [beer.se] - darüber musste ich lachen. Abgesehen davon, es sollte erwähnt werden, dass die Promotion dann von den aktiven Benutzern in die Rotation gewählt werden muss (Score: 6 [bei den meisten]). Bei den Sprachen denke ich ist das nicht so das Problem, bei anderen wohl eher doch.

Comment: I went through a bunch of Stack Exchange meta sites to collect ideas for site promotion; see [Additional site promotion ideas](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/417/additional-site-promotion-ideas) on Language Learning Meta.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

In my opinion, the German language (and the country) makes mainly positive associations (high-tech, high level industry, science, etc) in the world and advertising the site SE-wide will have a positive effect to the whole network.

Most of the sites have some support of community ads, i.e. they allow the community to decide, which banners they want to show on the site and in which proportion. We can easily initiate this by suggesting this ads on the meta sites, on them we have our other stackexchange accounts. It is going by simply posting the logo in the meta site, and then the community will decide by voting, if they want to help the site with ads or not.

The communities on most metas tend to vote more positive to our initiations, if

- we have a high reputation on that site,
- or, we are popular on them (what also tends to correlate with our reputation).

Examples: [MathSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/community-promotion-ads-2016), [Worlbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/community-promotion-ads-2016), [Japanese SE](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/community-promotion-ads-2016).

But: To do that, we should provide a German SE logo!